# Does a quadratic covariance function imply joint Gaussian distribution?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, covariance, joint-distribution

Consider a linear model $f(x) = \phi(x)^\top w$; where x is deterministic, $\phi$ is some fixed transformation, $w$ is independent and  $w\sim \mathcal{N(0, \Sigma_p)}$. The covariance function is $Cov(f(x),f(y)^\top) = \phi(x)^\top \Sigma_p \phi(y)$. Does this imply that the joint distribution of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ is Gaussian?

Comment: This has been answered in many, many threads: since $f$ is a linear transformation of a multivariate Normal distribution, it is itself multivariate Normal.  Indeed, this property characterizes Normal distributions.  The information about the covariance function, about $\phi$, and even about $x$ and $y$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a linear combination of jointly Gaussian random variables is Gaussian. You do not need to turn to covariance functions. The covariance function calculation is separate... The Gaussian property is most easily proven using [moment generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).

Answer (score 2):

A random vector $X = (X_1, ..., X_k)$ is said to have a multivariate Gaussian distribution iff. one of the following equivalent conditions is satisfied (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition):

1. Every univariate linear combination of its components $Y = a_1X_1 + ... + a_kX_k$ is normally distributed.
2. There exists a vector $Z = (Z_1, ..., Z_d)$ (with $d$ potentially being smaller than $k$) of *independent* univariate Gaussians and a matrix $A$ and a vector $\mu$ such that $X = AZ + \mu$
3. $X$ has a certain characteristic function.

Using 1. we see that $f(x)$ is nothing else but a constant vector times a multivariate Gaussian, hence a univariate Gaussian. The same holds for $f(y)$. Now if you assume that $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are independent (i.e. the $w$ in $f(x)$ and the $w$ in $f(y)$ are independent which I assume is true as $x$ and $y$ are two different observations or something that are unrelated) then $(f(x), f(y))$ is a vector consisting of two independent univariate Gaussians. By condition 2. this is a multivariate Gaussian.

A quick remark on your condition: Since $x$ and $y$ are not at all random, you compute *any* covariance between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ (this matrix always "exists" but may have infinite entries). How should that in general imply that there is some structure on the variables when any variable paired in that way with any other variable has 'some' covariance matrix?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.wu.ece.ufl.edu/books/math/probability/jointlygaussian.pdf

In the wikipedia definition it says "A random vector $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is said \underline{to have} a multivariate Gaussian distribution... ". If I join this formulation with the material I attached then I interpret it as the definition on wikipedia says that a joint Gaussian exists for random variables satisfying the conditions you stated.

Comment: I don't understand you remark. Anyhow, note that $f$ is a random process.

Comment: Erm... wait, there are different issues here... first of all I do not understand your comment in total. What exactly is the problem with the Gaussian? Secondly: what is the random variable (you call it f(x)) you are considering? It is $\omega \mapsto z w(\omega)$ where $z=\phi(x)$ is just a constant vector, right?

Comment: The comment is meant like this: you state: „I computed the covariance Matrix and it is A. Is the random vector Gaussian now?“ and the answer is obviously „no“ because any random vector has a covariance matrix, in particular any vector of random variables that is *not* Gaussian...

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot the most important point in condition 2... I’ll edit